# Display detailed contact card if contact has more than 1 phone number

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode8, abpeoplepickerview

If a contact has only 1 phone number, I want to select it. If it has more than 1 phone number, then I want to display the detailed contact card.

I am using the below method, which works fine.

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    if (person != nil) {
        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) == 1) {
            //Do stuff to select phone number
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I implement this Utility method to display Detailed Contact card:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {

    NSString* phone = nil;
    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
        CFIndex index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(phoneNumbers, identifier);
        phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, index);
    }
}
```

but this method never gets called?
If I comment out the first method, then the second method gets called. How can I call both, or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do this  is to add a `predicate` before starting the `peoplePicker`in this case it would be:

```
-(void)getContacts {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    if ([peoplePicker respondsToSelector:@selector(setPredicateForSelectionOfPerson:)])
    {
        // The people picker will select a person that has exactly one phone number and call peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:,
        // otherwise the people picker will present an ABPersonViewController for the user to pick one of the Phone Numbers.
        peoplePicker.predicateForSelectionOfPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumbers.@count = 1"];

    }
    [self presentViewController:peoplePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

similarly in case of emailAdresses, replace  : `@"phoneNumbers.@count = 1"` with `@"emailAddresses.@count = 1"`.